# How can I make a boolean from a SELECT statement in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the following statement that returns 2 ids but how can I return true or false instead?

```
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE datetime > NOW();
```

I also know there is this but I dont know how to adapt it to my case:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 2 > 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END;
```

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to return a boolean? mysql does provide the `BOOLEAN` datatype but it is internally stored as `TINYINT` where non-zero is true and 0 is false.

Comment: @RinkeshP, no it can be a Tinyint also :)

Comment: *how can I return true or false instead?* What condition do you want to return this boolean for? Do you want to check does at least one `id` which matches `WHERE datetime > NOW()` exists? or maybe you need to check that there exists strictly two `id` values matched? or something else? Or you want to receive all `id` values and for each of them the result of checking for the expression `datetime > NOW()`?

Comment: Like my goal is to add an entry to a database using insert into tablename (xxx,xxx) values ('value', 'hash of concat of value and boolean i am talking about'); @Akina

Comment: https://xyproblem.info - this is your case.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have an explicit boolean type, instead it treats ints as true/false. Non-zero and non-null values (eg, 1) is evaluated as true, 0 is evaluated as false.

Depending on the version of MySQL that you're using, you may have access to what the docs refer to as [Boolean Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html), so TRUE and FALSE. These just evaluate to 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: *1 is considered true, 0 is considered false.* Incorrect. Any non-zero and non-NULL value is considered as TRUE. Looking at backward convertion, TRUE is an alias (not considered as) of 1 and FALSE is an alias of 0.

Comment: I'll update the answer with that detail.

Answer (score 1):

As you have suggested, you may use a `CASE` expression here:

```sql
SELECT id, CASE WHEN datetime > NOW() THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS outcome
FROM tablename;
```

You also could make the above more concise by using the `IF()` function:

```sql
SELECT id, IF(datetime > NOW(), 'True', 'False') AS outcome
FROM tablename;
```